# Mex Cuda Dynamic Allocation / Slow mex code

Tags: c++, matlab, dynamic, cuda, mex

I Have cuda/C++ code that returns C++ host-side arrays. I wanted to manipulate these arrays in MATLAB so I rewrote my code in mex format and compiled with mex.

I got it to work by passing preallocated arrays from MATLAB into the mex script but this slowed things down insanely. (54 seconds vs 14 seconds without mex)

Here's the slow solution for a simplified, no input 1 output version of my code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "gpu/mxGPUArray.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "curand.h"
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#define iterations 159744
#define transMatrixSize 2592 // Just for clarity. Do not change. No need to adjust this value for this simulation.
#define reps 1024 // Is equal to blocksize. Do not change without proper source code adjustments.
#define integralStep 13125  // Number of time steps to be averaged at the tail of the Force-Time curves to get Steady State Force

__global__ void kern(float *masterForces, ...)
{

int globalIdx = ((blockIdx.x + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x)) * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y)) + (threadIdx.x + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x));
...

  ...
   {
...
      {
          masterForces[i] = buffer[0]/24576.0;
      }

      }
   }
...
}



}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])
{
   ...

plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(iterations,1,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
float *h_F0 = (float*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);


//Device input vectors
float *d_F0;

..
// Allocate memory for each vector on GPU
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_F0, iterations * sizeof(float));
...




//////////////////////////////////////////////LAUNCH ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

kern<<<1, 1024>>>( d_F0);



//////////////////////////////////////////////RETRIEVE DATA ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


cudaMemcpyAsync( h_F0 , d_F0 , iterations * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);



///////////////////Free Memory///////////////////


cudaDeviceReset();
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Why so slow?

EDIT: Mex was compiling with an older architecture (SM_13) INSTEAD OF SM_35. Now the time makes sense. (16 s with mex, 14 s with c++/cuda only)

Comment: To which MathWorks example are you referring?

Comment: standard cuda mex example "timestwo"

http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html

Comment: That example takes a `gpuArray` input and returns a `gpuArray output`.  You want to take regular arrays in/out, right?

Comment: See my UPDATED ANSWER. Also, remove `delete h_F0;` when using `mxCreateNumericMatrix`.

Comment: Really nothing to clean up that I can see.  Be sure not to time the first run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a `mxGPUArray` if the outputs of your CUDA code are plain-old-data (POD) host-side (vs. device-side) arrays, like your `Forces1` array of `float`s created with `new`.  The MathWorks example that you are referencing is probably demonstrating the use of MATLAB's `gpuArray` and built-in CUDA functionality, rather than how to pass data to and from regular CUDA functions within a MEX function.

If you can initialize `Forces1` (or `h_F0` in your full code) *outside* and before the CUDA function (e.g. in the `mexFunction`), then the solution is just to change from `new` to one of the `mxCreate*` functions (i.e. `mxCreateNumericArray`, `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`, `mxCreateNumericMatrix`, etc.), and then pass the data pointer to your CUDA function:

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(iterations,1,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
float *h_F0 = (float*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);
// myCudaWrapper(...,h_F0 ,...) /* i.e. cudaMemcpyAsync(h_F0,d_F0,...)
```

The only changes to your code are thus:

**Replace**:

```
float *h_F0 = new float[(iterations)];
```

with

```
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(iterations,1,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);
float *h_F0 = (float*) mxGetData(plhs[0]);
```

**Remove**:

```
delete h_F0;
```

Note: If instead your CUDA code owned the output host-side array, then you would have to *copy the data* into an `mxArray`.  This is because unless you allocate the `mexFunction` outputs with the `mx` API, any data buffer you assign (e.g. with `mxSetData`) will not be handled by the MATLAB memory manager, and you will have a segfault or at best, a memory leak.

Comment: If I were to initialize Forces1 in MATLAB and pass it into the mex function, would I suffer performance loss compared to initializing Forces1 in the cuda/C++ script?

Comment: No.  When you pass the `float*` into your "CUDA/C++ function", it is just a regular buffer.  An `mxArray` is just the container.

Comment: Im trying your solution now

Comment: Presumably you have a CUDA (C) function, with a C++ wrapper with copies an output device-array into the output host-array?  If so, that's the only operation on the MATLAB-owned output array, `Forces1`.

Comment: Yes. It makes an array on the host, runs a kernel, and then copies the kernel's results into the host array

Comment: What is "N" in plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(N,1,mxSINGLE_CLASS,mxREAL);

Comment: Rows.  See [this docs page for `mxCreateNumericMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatenumericmatrix.html). I should have used `m`.  :)

Comment: I passed in the arrays from MATLAB. However, upon attempting to compile, I get an error at the line

plhs[0] = Forces1;

It's saying error: a value of type
"float *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "mxArray *"

Comment: You shouldn't do `plhs[0] = Forces1;`  You are using `mxCreateNumericMatrix` to set `plhs[0]`. Can you post the other C++ and CUDA code, or at least any function declarations?

Comment: posted. Thank you for the help, I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Wait I got it to work. I think its way too slow, though. 54 seconds vs 14 seconds in C++

Comment: Note sure why it's slower. Debug build? No optimizations?  The only access of `h_F0` is with the memory copy from device (`cudaMemcpyAsync`).  I don't see why that should be slower, sorry.  BTW, where is `mexFunction` and how does that relate to `main`?

Comment: My Matlab code is just this:

x = zeros(1,159744,'single'); output1 = myMexFunction(x);

Comment: Could it be that I'm not cleaning up properly? Should I try destroying any mex constructs?

Comment: OOOOH LMFAO. I THINK IT WAS COMPILING WITH AN OLDER CUDA ARCHETECURE (encoded in the mex XML file)

Comment: LET ME TRY TO RECOMPILE WITH NEW ARCHETECTURE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57807/discussion-between-user3754725-and-chappjc).